# Could not parse the remainder: ',' from ''twitter:source_delete','

Tags: javascript, django, django-views

> I want to append td to my table using ajax but I have a little problem, how to add the source.twitter_id in url?? the error that I got is "Could not parse the remainder: ',' from ''twitter:source_delete',' "
>
> I tried also  {% url 'twitter:source_delete', source.twitter_id %} it also error.

**javascript**

```
function appendToUsrTable(source) {
console.log(source.twitter_id)
    $("#sourceTable > tbody:last-child").append(`
         <tr class="record" id="source-${source.twitter_id}">
          <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
          <td>${source.source_acct}</td>
          <td><p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete"><a href="{% url 
            'twitter:source_delete' ${source.twitter_id} %}" class="source_delete btn btn-
             danger btn-xs" 
             data-title="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete"><span class="las la-trash-alt 
 del_s"></span></a></p></td>
       </tr>
`);
```

}

**views.py**

```
class CreateCrudUser(View):
def  get(self, request):
    
    name_source = request.GET.get('source_acct', None)
    print(name_source)
    obj = Source.objects.create(
        source_acct = name_source
        )

    source = {'twitter_id':obj.twitter_id,'source_acct':obj.source_acct}

    data = {
    'source': source
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

this problem is raising because empty(null value) of `source.twitter_id`
so it is better to check if source.twitter_id is null or not

Answer (score 0):

You can try to define the url variable outside of java script template literal like this :

```
function appendToUsrTable(source) {
    const url = "{% url 'twitter:source_delete' source.twitter_id %}"
    console.log(source.twitter_id)
    $("#sourceTable > tbody:last-child").append(`
         <tr class="record" id="source-${source.twitter_id}">
           <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
           <td>${source.source_acct}</td>
           <td><p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete"><a href=${url} class="source_delete btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-title="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete"><span class="las la-trash-alt del_s"></span></a></p></td>
         </tr>
`);
```

**NB :** be careful about combine **Django template variable** with **Java Script template literal**.

Answer (score 0):

> I found a solution.
> thank you!

```
let sour = source.twitter_id;
var url = "{% url 'twitter:source_delete' 123 %}".replace(/123/,sour.toString());
```